# Get all elements with `position:fixed` in an HTML page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

Reason for doing that: I'm debugging css of my webpage.. some elements appeared and they're not supposed to appear. I suspect it is the issue with element positioning.. therefore I want to find these positioned element and check one by one.

Comment: what's your question?

Comment: @SudiptaMaiti See title?

Comment: Not sure why didnt you tag this question with jquery when you are upvoting ans with jquery

Comment: @user2181397 oops.. forgot. Would do :)

Comment: @songyy: I edited the answer to include a plain javascript approach

Comment: @geckob Thanks, I didn't know the `getComputedStyle` before :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This one is using jQuery. I hope you are find with it.

```
 var find = $('*').filter(function () { 
        return $(this).css('position') == 'fixed';
    });
```

I think this one works using a pure javascript:

```
var elems = document.body.getElementsByTagName("*");
var len = elems.length

for (var i=0;i<len;i++) {

    if (window.getComputedStyle(elems[i],null).getPropertyValue('position') == 'fixed') {
        console.log(elems[i])
    }

}
```

Comment: @songyy: Glad it helps. Please vote if you think it is useful. Thanks

Answer (score 9):

Here is an ES6 version that gives you an array of these elements for further processing:

```
let fixedElements = [...document.body.getElementsByTagName("*")].filter(
    x => getComputedStyle(x, null).getPropertyValue("position") === "fixed"
);
```

Answer (score 2):

**Warnings that apply to all answers:**

- This is a slow operation. On a large-enough page, this operation can take 100ms or more, which is **a lot** for a single operation. You shouldn't need this unless you're developing a browser extension.
- Now `sticky` elements can act as `fixed` elements in some cases

---

Having said that, here's the shortest and most efficient version to do this:

```js
const fixed = [].filter.call(document.all, e => getComputedStyle(e).position == 'fixed');
```

Here's a version that includes `sticky` elements, but they're not exactly equivalent, it depends on what you're looking for:

```js
const all = [].filter.call(
  document.all,
  e => ['fixed', 'sticky'].includes(getComputedStyle(e).position)
);
```

If you're feeling *modern*, replace `document.all` with `document.querySelectorAll('*')`, but the former will likely work forever.

Answer (score 1):

`document.querySelector('*[style="position:fixed"]')`

The `*` item specifies all tag names.  The `[]` indicate that you're looking for an attribute. You want your style attribute to have `position:fixed`.

If you aren't using jQuery, this is probably going to be your simplest option.

Comment: Did you tried it ? Look at this jsfiddle 
https://jsfiddle.net/0xysh9wh/2/ and please update

Comment: The `document.querySelector()` method only looks at tag attributes. Without using jQuery or another DOM manipulation framework, you'll have to assemble all elements using `querySelectorAll('*')` (though I'd replace that '*' with a `div` or somthing) then use a linear search trying to match `element.style.position` to `"fixed"`

Comment: Also a note, I did a little testing, and it seems that jsfiddle doesn't support the NodeList return of `querySelectorAll()`, so you'll only get the first element.  Try running it your console (something like `var a = document.querySelectorAll('*'); console.log(a)`) and you'll see that you have an iteratable object

Comment: @wilusdaman, if the element is styled by a cascade style sheet (not its style attribute) you have to use getComputedStyle, `element.style.position` will be empty in the fiddle.
and your selector is just too localized,  even this wouldn't work : https://jsfiddle.net/0xysh9wh/3/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var elements = $('*').filter(function () { 
    return this.style.position == 'fixed';
});
```

It will give you all elements having position fixed.

Comment: I've tried this: `$('*').filter(function (idx, ele) { console.log(ele.style.position); return true;});` but interestingly... i'm getting no element that is fixed position (either relative, or absolute)

Comment: I actually think ur way *should work*.. but I don't know what's wrong either

Comment: I believe this will only work when the styling is inline.

Comment: @geckob Ahh yeah haha :)