# Select all elements with position 'fixed' using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I select all elements in an html page with position 'fixed' using jQuery

Comment: What was the problem with the solution that you have tried?

Answer (score 1):

```
var find = $('*').filter(function () { 
    return $(this).css('position') == 'fixed';
});
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/35055063/7869582

Comment: Don't do that. When it's a duplicate, vote to close it. Don't answer

Comment: And in particular don't copy other answers